# Создание дубликатов сообщений RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

Сообщения приходят в очередь напрямую (Используя точку обмена по умолчанию, типа direct, routing ключом служит имя очереди).
Необходимо отслеживать поступление новых сообщений  в очередь и отправлять их в другую очередь не удаляя из первой. Такого вида дублирование.

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту задачу. Пробовал использовать shovel плагин, но он удаляет сообщения из очереди...

PS: нужно решить с использованием только веб интерфейса. Нет возможности изменить код дабы сообщения отправлялись в обе очереди или на точку обмена.